# Надо правильно написать программу,не могу решить дз по инфе)

Tags: windows, pascal, pascalabc.net, freepascal

Вот что могу предоставить,без понятия как исправлять,можете сказать что в нем не так,или что надо сделать.

```
Program uravneniya;
begin integer
Procedure ur1; 
vara,b,c,k: integer; x:real;
begin
Writeln('Рeшаемуравнениевида ax - b = c');
Writeln();
Writeln('Введите значения переменных а, в, с, через пробел');
readln(a,b,c);
writeln('Решаемуравнение:',a,'x - ',b,' = ',c);
writeln();
Writeln(a,'x - ',b,' = ',c);
Writeln(a,'x = ',c,' + ',b);
Writeln(a,'x = ',c+b);
k:=c+b;
Writeln('x = ',k,'/',a);
Writeln('x = ',round(k/a*100)/100);
end; 
Procedure ur3;
vara,b,c,k: integer; x:real;
begin
Writeln(' Решаем  уравнение вида ах + в = с');
Writeln();
Writeln('Введите значения переменных а, в, с, через пробел');
readln(a,b,c);
writeln('Решаемуравнение:',a,'x + ',b,' = ',c);
writeln();
Writeln(a,'x + ',b,' = ',c);
Writeln(a,'x = ',c,' - ',b);
Writeln(a,'x = ',c-b);
k:=c-b;
Writeln('x = ',k,'/',a);
Writeln('x = ',round(k/a*100)/100);
end;
Procedure ur2;
vara,b,c,k: integer; x:real;
begin
Writeln(' Решаем уравнения вида а - вx = с');
Writeln();
Writeln('Введите значения переменных а, в, с, через пробел');
readln(a,b,c);
writeln('Решаемуравнение:',a,' - ',b,'x  = ',c);
writeln();
Writeln(a,' - ',b,'x = ',c);
Writeln(b,'x = ',a,' - ',c);
Writeln(b,'x = ',a-c);
k:=a-c;
Writeln('x = ',k,'/',b);
Writeln('x = ',round(k/b*100)/100);
end;
Procedure ur4;
vara,b,c,k: integer; x:real;
begin
Writeln('Решаем уравнение вида а + вx = с');
Writeln();
Writeln('Введите значения переменных а, в, с, через пробел');
readln(a,b,c);
writeln('Решаемуравнение:',a,' + ',b,'x  = ',c);
writeln();
Writeln(a,' + ',b,'x = ',c);
Writeln(b,'x = ',c,' - ',a);
Writeln(b,'x = ',c-a);
k:=c-a;
Writeln('x = ',k,'/',b);
Writeln('x = ',round(k/b*100)/100);
end;
begin
WriteLn('Решаем все виды линейных уравнений');
WriteLn(' 1. ax - b = c');
WriteLn(' 2. a - bx = c');
WriteLn(' 3. ax + b = c');
WriteLn(' 4. a + bx = c');
WriteLn('Выберите тип решаемого уравнения');
read(n);
Case n of
1: ur1;  
2: ur2;
3: ur3;
4: ur4;  
else
WriteLn('Выбран неверный тип уравнения');
End;
end.
```

Comment: Прикрепите, пожалуйста, текст вашей задачи

Comment: Выполнение проекта/ Листинг программы находится в файле,Завершить выполнение проекта.

Вот что написано в задании,в файле находиться код

Answer (score -1):

Минимальные правки синтаксиса

```pascal
program uravneniya;

procedure ur1;
var
    a, b, c, k: integer;
    x: real;
begin
    Writeln('Рeшаемуравнениевида ax - b = c');
    Writeln();
    Writeln('Введите значения переменных а, в, с, через пробел');
    readln(a, b, c);
    writeln('Решаемуравнение:', a, 'x - ', b, ' = ', c);
    writeln();
    Writeln(a, 'x - ', b, ' = ', c);
    Writeln(a, 'x = ', c, ' + ', b);
    Writeln(a, 'x = ', c + b);
    k := c + b;
    Writeln('x = ', k, '/', a);
    Writeln('x = ', round(k / a * 100) / 100);
end;

procedure ur3;
var
    a, b, c, k: integer;
    x: real;
begin
    Writeln(' Решаем  уравнение вида ах + в = с');
    Writeln();
    Writeln('Введите значения переменных а, в, с, через пробел');
    readln(a, b, c);
    writeln('Решаемуравнение:', a, 'x + ', b, ' = ', c);
    writeln();
    Writeln(a, 'x + ', b, ' = ', c);
    Writeln(a, 'x = ', c, ' - ', b);
    Writeln(a, 'x = ', c - b);
    k := c - b;
    Writeln('x = ', k, '/', a);
    Writeln('x = ', round(k / a * 100) / 100);
end;

procedure ur2;
var
    a, b, c, k: integer;
    x: real;
begin
    Writeln(' Решаем уравнения вида а - вx = с');
    Writeln();
    Writeln('Введите значения переменных а, в, с, через пробел');
    readln(a, b, c);
    writeln('Решаемуравнение:', a, ' - ', b, 'x  = ', c);
    writeln();
    Writeln(a, ' - ', b, 'x = ', c);
    Writeln(b, 'x = ', a, ' - ', c);
    Writeln(b, 'x = ', a - c);
    k := a - c;
    Writeln('x = ', k, '/', b);
    Writeln('x = ', round(k / b * 100) / 100);
end;

procedure ur4;
var
    a, b, c, k: integer;
    x: real;
begin
    Writeln('Решаем уравнение вида а + вx = с');
    Writeln();
    Writeln('Введите значения переменных а, в, с, через пробел');
    readln(a, b, c);
    writeln('Решаемуравнение:', a, ' + ', b, 'x  = ', c);
    writeln();
    Writeln(a, ' + ', b, 'x = ', c);
    Writeln(b, 'x = ', c, ' - ', a);
    Writeln(b, 'x = ', c - a);
    k := c - a;
    Writeln('x = ', k, '/', b);
    Writeln('x = ', round(k / b * 100) / 100);
end;

var
    n: integer;

begin
    WriteLn('Решаем все виды линейных уравнений');
    WriteLn(' 1. ax - b = c');
    WriteLn(' 2. a - bx = c');
    WriteLn(' 3. ax + b = c');
    WriteLn(' 4. a + bx = c');
    WriteLn('Выберите тип решаемого уравнения');
    read(n);
    case n of
        1: ur1;  
        2: ur2;
        3: ur3;
        4: ur4;  
    else
        WriteLn('Выбран неверный тип уравнения');
    End;
end.
```